# Did I use the correct key signiture for this 12 bars blues?

Tags: guitar, theory, sheet-music, key-signatures

[QuincyPenolaSheetMusic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lnxur5JOdeppv38MF8wflw5blxR8uvdl/view?usp=sharing)

Any input would be fine. I was wondering if another key signature would have made it more easy, as there is a couple of double flats.

Comment: as I can't comment my own answer I post it here:
still you didn't tell us with what program you're working. I've opened it with finale: first with the option "set key signature" just to see what will come out if I set key C. as you've noticed the file is named "12 Bars Blues Shuffle in E.mid"
then I' ve opened it with the the option "key signature: use the file's"  and it worked fine: the reading was adjusted and ultra  correct.

Comment: I used a program called noteflight you can go to Noteflight.com and use the midi file there I beilve. Im going to redo it in a program called Notion by presonus. Notions will allow me to do the sheet music aswell as guitar tablature.Notion isnt as good as Noteflight, Its in the key of E so i used the E major key signiture

Comment: If you can't solve it I will post you the copy of the result of finale.

Comment: sure that would be cool

Comment: @Albrecht - you can always comment on your own posts

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the product of an imported midi file.

**the key is E (major)**

you don't tell us what program you use.

if you don't have the utility for editing enharmonic spelling as "favor sharps", you might just save the right hand (export as midi file and import again pre selecting the key: E

or the option **"select key signature of the file**"

the double flats will be exchanged as g#  (bb to a, db to c# and so on)

you may change the enharmonics also by hand, this will be a good exercise.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ie0cKCNLxZ3dKZt8K8tUZM-vYuBqpbeC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: heres the midi, I use noteflight as its the best online scoring. Yes I will do as you said

Answer (score 0):

You may be combining two questions here.
If you want the key of E Maj, then stay with the signature you have.  If you change the signature, then you'll be shifting the entire piece into a new key, with perhaps a different feeling or different overtone resonances dominating.

As to notatation, a reasonably experienced musician should be fine with, e.g., your notation of  Gnat / Ab  . I've seen some scores where that would be notated F## / G# (where the G# is in the key signature).   For your Bbb measures,  I would recommend B ,  A,  Bb (the first B natural is in the key signature)

There's nothing wrong with notating Db if that fits the chord progression intended, or moving it to a C# (in key signature) to make it easier on the performer.  Dealer's choice.

Answer (score 0):

The key signature's good.  The lower stave is good.  The upper stave has decided to use flats in a '4 sharps' environment!   Find alternative spellings that fit in better.